# Why am I getting a syntax error when I try to create a code label in C# (for goto)?

Tags: c#, goto

Consider the following:

```
class abc {
    public void foobar() {
        while(true) {
            while(true) {
                goto mylabel;
            }
        }
        mylabel:
    }
}
```

I get a syntax error on the : of mylabel that says:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

Am I losing my mind here? What on earth am I doing wrong? I have googled up and down and it seems my syntax is correct.

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind:  1) There's no statement at mylabel. ("The target of a goto identifier statement is the labeled statement with the given label. I". See  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664758(v=vs.71).aspx  2) I'd expect mylabel to be in scope, but if I'm wrong, that's the second possibility.  

Try adding a Console.WriteLine after mylabel, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the label, you need a statement. A closing `}` isn't a statement, it is ending a block of code. You can use the [empty statement (`;`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739(v=vs.71).aspx) here:

```
mylabel: ;
```

The linked page even states:

> Also, an empty statement can be used to declare a label just before the closing "}" of a block:

Comment: Or you could just use `return` instead of `goto` if there isn't anything to execute.

Comment: Man I feel dumb now. If I have just written one  more line of code that would have been apparent. haha. I will mark as answered as soon as the window allows me to.

Comment: @JohnWu yes, in this example you could. But it appears the code provided has been simplified to an MCVE, so this is the more generic answer.